# Why are iPhone CSS Breakpoints not working

Tags: css, iphone, breakpoints

I'm trying to make a responsive website using CSS Media Queries to create breakpoints for my iPhone 12 Mini and my partner's iPhone 12 Pro Max. I found the following viewport widths from several different sites all confirming the same thing:

```
iPhone 12 Mini viewport width is 375px
iPhone 12 Pro Max viewport width is 428px
```

The following is my css code:

```
// iPhone 12 Mini
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .wine-list h1 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}

// iPhone 12 Pro Max
@media screen and (min-width: 376px) {
    .wine-list h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

The above code worked once before on both devices.

However, when I made one small change to the `min-width` value, the breakpoints stopped working correctly and started using the main css file. So I changed it back. But both devices still refuse to break appropriately. **I do not understand. This seems to defy all laws of computer science.** If it worked before, why won't it work again? What am I overlooking?

I test the website directly on the iPhone devices themselves, I do not use any emulators. I tested the code in Safari and Chrome. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably cache. Voting for close because it's not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was breaking because I used `//` to comment instead of `/*  */`. CSS should technically never use `//` to comment anything. I can't believe I overlooked this. I should have known it was something so simple. ‍♂️ Everything works now across all browsers.